# Call to python class constructor from rust with pyo3 spawns new processes

Tags: rust, pyo3, tensorboardx

I'm writing code in *Rust* but using the crate `pyo3` to call *Python* libraries (specifically `tensorflow` and `tensorboardX`). However, when I call the class initializer for `tensorboardX.SummaryWriter` from *Rust* it starts a new process that restarts the whole program (starts executing the `main` function from the start), which in turn will try to initialize a new `SummaryWriter`, thus spawning an endless sequence of processes.

Here is a minimal working example :

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Start");
    pyo3::prepare_freethreaded_python();
    let x: PyResult<PyObject> = Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let tbx = PyModule::import(py, "tensorboardX")?;
        let x = tbx.getattr("SummaryWriter")?.call0()?;
        Ok(x.to_object(py))
    });
    let x = x.unwrap();
    println!("End ({:?})", x);
}
```

When I run this example it prints an infinite loop of

```
Start
End (Py(0x101025e50))
Start
End (Py(0x1011b9e50))
Start
End (Py(0x1008fde50))
...
```

and each is printed by a different process (which in turn makes it difficult to kill, I had to use the `killall` command to kill the process by name since each is quite short lived).

**Note:** It is a bit tricky to run because it needs to have the path to a Python environment that has tensorboardX installed (I had to add a `.cargo/config.toml` file at the root of my project with the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` pointing to the environment :

```
[env]
PYTHONPATH = "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages"
```

Anybody knows why it spawns processes instead of simply returning a SummaryWriter object ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you isolate exactly what spawns the process? The import, the `getattr()`, the `call0()`, or the `to_object()`?